# using docker image from registry with terraform

Tags: docker, terraform

Im trying to use an docker image which is hosted on the docker hub registry with terraform. When i run `terraform apply` is says that it does not exist or docker login is required. And then it fails with an requested access to the resource is denied. What am i doing wrong?

main.tf:

```
provider "docker" {
    host = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"

    registry_auth {
        address = "registry.hub.docker.com"
        username = "username"
        password = "passwword"
    }
}

resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name          = "data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name"
  pull_triggers = ["data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.sha256_digest"]
}

data "docker_registry_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:latest"
}
```

versions.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "terraform-providers/docker"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

error output:

```
Error: Unable to read Docker image into resource: Unable to pull image data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name: error pulling image data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

  on main.tf line 11, in resource "docker_image" "ubuntu":
  11: resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the full error output when you run `terraform apply`?

Comment: yeah sure, i added the error output

Comment: As the answer below says; you need to remove the quotation marks. It turns the syntax used in the docs is outdated where quotations are still required. I'm running terraform v0.13.3 which does not require quotations anymore, and errors on it. Not sure from which version this error will occur, but atleast from v0.13.3.

Comment: You never wanted the quotes like that. You would have wanted to use the interpolation syntax in Terraform 0.11 and below which would be `"${data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name}"`. This is still valid syntax in Terraform 0.12 and above but it will warn you that instead you should just use `data.docker_registry_image.ubuntu.name`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the four quotation marks from within the `resource "docker_image" "ubuntu"` block.

Comment: This looks to be the correct answer here but normally for minor/typo answered questions we instead comment on the question to point out the issue and then vote to close as a typo as it's unlikely it will be helpful for future people.